# configure: error: Can't LÖVE without DevIL

Tags: lua, love2d

I'm using Linux Manjaro, and I intend to install LÖVE2D, a framework for 2D developpement, but I'm facing a problem : When I type "./configure" on the command line, I receive the following message :

> checking for library containing ilInit... no
>   configure: error: Can't LÖVE without DevIL

Then I installed DevIL. It seemed to work, although some dependencies didn't get a proper install.
For one of them, I get this :

> ../../include/lcms2.h:227:22: erreur: expected identifier before numeric constant
>    #       define FALSE 0

And for another (libmng-1.0.10), and can't even find the "configure" file, so I can't even compile it.

So how the hell do I fix this ?

Answer (score 0):

One thing that comes to mind is DPKG. I remember using it, on ARCH LINUX not long ago, to install Love2D from a .deb on their website. As far as I know, Manjaro is based on ARCH so this same solution should also work for you.

To sum it up: Install DPKG, grab the deb from love2d.org and install it that way.

Comment: And how do I install dpgk on Arch ?

Comment: I just installer DPKG from yaourt. It seemed to work, but when I install the deb package, I've got the following message : dpkg : Error : fail to read the « info » file « /usr/local/var/lib/dpkg/status » : Impossible to find the folder or file

Answer (score 0):

On Arch Linux you need to install "DevIL" as well as all the other dependencies.

You should be able to do this by running as root from the terminal (for 0.9.x):

`pacman -S luajit physfs freetype2 devil mpg123 openal libvorbis libmodplug sdl2 shared-mime-info hicolor-icon-theme desktop-file-utils`

Manjaro is similar enough to Arch Linux that this should work.

For a full list of dependencies for Arch Linux for different releases, [see the wiki here](https://www.love2d.org/wiki/Building_L%C3%96VE#Arch_Linux).

Keep in mind that if you looking to install older versions (or development releases) of `love`, they are also in maintained packages in `Community` and the `AUR`. See `love05`, `love07`, `love08` and `love-hg`.